# Getting error 400 on Google publisher api Subscriptions.Get with test subscriptions autorenew

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I am trying to use the Google Publisher API for backend upgrade/downgrade operations of the subscriptions of my Android app.

I published the app in Alpha channel and having some testers making "test" purchases. 
Everything looks good during the same day the subscription has been generated. I can see valid data using the purchase token, calling the method:

```
Purchases.Subscriptions.Get
```

My problem is that when the "test" subscription renews automatically (the day after), looks like the purchase token is not usable anymore and when I call the method:

```
Purchases.Subscriptions.Get
```

I get this error:

> The purchase token does not match the package name. [400]

Looks like that when a "test" subscription renews automatically, the Purchase token changes as well.

- Does anybody have my same problem?
- Any ideas why the purchase token changes on subscription auto-renew?
- Shouldn't the purchase token remain always the same even after an auto-renew?

Comment: I spent 2 days to understand whats the hack is going on. The problem was that I really make mistake in word of package name. In my case problem was in Firebase->Functions->Config->App->package_name so. Also you can add https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-play-billing-validator to make validation before use main purchase functions. So re check it twice and all goes work.